# Gekko: Smooth control variables

Tags: optimization, ode, gekko

I'm trying to solve a DAE boundary value problem involving three control variables. In the MWE shown below there are 8 unknown variables which have to be optimized at final time using the three control variables. However, the final solution I obtain has sharply fluctuating control variables which are not appropriate for control. I tried imposing penalty using the option DCOST but the solutions don't converge. Is there any other way to do this?

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import special



tg=10
sample_rate= 100
tlist= np.linspace(0,tg,int(tg*sample_rate))

m = GEKKO()
m.time= tlist

#given function of time

sigma= 1.25

def eps_G(t):
    A= np.pi/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma*special.erf(tg/(2*np.sqrt(2)*sigma))- np.exp(-(0-tg/2)**2/(2*sigma**2))*tg)
    B= A*np.exp(-(0-tg/2)**2/(2*sigma**2))
    return  A*np.exp(-((t-(tg/2))/sigma)** 2/2)-B

omg_0= [eps_G(t) for t in tlist]
omg_1= np.array(omg_0)
omg= m.MV(omg_1)
omg.STATUS=0

#control variables

omx= m.MV(value=0, lb= -2, ub= 2)
omy= m.MV(value=0, lb= -2, ub= 2)
det= m.MV(value=0, lb= -2, ub= 2)

omx.STATUS= 1
omy.STATUS= 1
det.STATUS= 1

#omx.DCOST=0.00001
#omy.DCOST=0.00001
#det.DCOST=0.00001

#numpy arrays for constructing equations

Hz= np.array([[0,0],[0,1]])
Hx= np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
Hy= np.array([[0,-1],[1,0]])


HRR= np.empty((2,2), dtype= object)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        HRR[i,j]= det*Hz[i,j]+ (omx/2)*Hx[i,j]

HRI= np.empty((2,2), dtype= object)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        HRI[i,j]=  (omy/2)*Hy[i,j]

#unknown variables

DR = m.Array(m.Var,(2,2), value=0, lb= -10, ub= 10)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        if i==j:
            DR[i,j].value = 1
        else:
            DR[i, j].value= 0

DI = m.Array(m.Var,(2,2),value=0, lb= -10, ub= 10)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        DI[i, j].value=0


#Equations

m.Equations([np.transpose(DR)[i,j]*DR[i,j].dt()+ np.transpose(DI)[i,j]*DI[i,j].dt()== np.dot(np.transpose(DR),np.dot(HRR, DI))[i,j]+np.dot(np.transpose(DR),np.dot(HRI, DR))[i,j]- np.dot(np.transpose(DI),np.dot(HRR, DR))[i,j]+np.dot(np.transpose(DI),np.dot(HRI, DI))[i,j] for i in range(2) for j in range(2) ])

m.Equations([np.transpose(DR)[i,j]*DI[i,j].dt()- np.transpose(DI)[i,j]*DR[i,j].dt()== (omg/2)*Hx[i,j]- np.dot(np.transpose(DR),np.dot(HRR, DR))[i,j]+np.dot(np.transpose(DR),np.dot(HRI, DI))[i,j]- np.dot(np.transpose(DI),np.dot(HRR, DI))[i,j]-np.dot(np.transpose(DI),np.dot(HRI, DR))[i,j] for i in range(2) for j in range(2) ])


#final time

p = np.zeros(int(tg*sample_rate))
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)


#Objectives

#m.Obj(omx*final)
#m.Obj(omy*final)
#m.Obj(det*final)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        m.Obj((DR[i,j]- np.identity(2)[i,j])*final)
        m.Obj(DI[i,j]*final)


# solve DAE

m.options.SOLVER= 3
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.MAX_ITER=500
m.solve(disp= True, debug=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem in 2 stages often helps. The first stage is an initialization without the `DCOST` values or with the manipulated variable (MV) `STATUS=0`. The second stage is the addition of the `DCOST` and possibly `DMAX` values to add hard constraints.

```py
# solve DAE
m.options.SOLVER= 3
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.MAX_ITER=500
m.solve(disp= True, debug=0)

# solve same problem
# don't update initial conditions with next time step
m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 0
# Soft Constraints
omx.DCOST=0.00001
omy.DCOST=0.00001
det.DCOST=0.00001
# Hard Constraints
#omx.DMAX=0.5
#omy.DMAX=0.5
#det.DMAX=0.5
m.options.MAX_ITER = 200
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)
```

Changing to the `APOPT` solver with `m.options.SOLVER=1` also helps it converge. `IPOPT` is better at finding an initial solution, but `APOPT` generally works better once the problem is initialized.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

tg=10
sample_rate= 10 # change back to 100
tlist= np.linspace(0,tg,int(tg*sample_rate))

m = GEKKO()
m.time= tlist

#given function of time
sigma= 1.25
def eps_G(t):
    A= np.pi/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)\
       *sigma*special.erf(tg/(2*np.sqrt(2)*sigma)) \
       - np.exp(-(0-tg/2)**2/(2*sigma**2))*tg)
    B= A*np.exp(-(0-tg/2)**2/(2*sigma**2))
    return  A*np.exp(-((t-(tg/2))/sigma)** 2/2)-B

omg_0= [eps_G(t) for t in tlist]
omg_1= np.array(omg_0)
omg= m.MV(omg_1)
omg.STATUS=0

#control variables
omx= m.MV(value=0, lb= -2, ub= 2)
omy= m.MV(value=0, lb= -2, ub= 2)
det= m.MV(value=0, lb= -2, ub= 2)

omx.STATUS= 1
omy.STATUS= 1
det.STATUS= 1

#numpy arrays for constructing equations

Hz= np.array([[0,0],[0,1]])
Hx= np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
Hy= np.array([[0,-1],[1,0]])

HRR= np.empty((2,2), dtype= object)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        HRR[i,j]= det*Hz[i,j]+ (omx/2)*Hx[i,j]

HRI= np.empty((2,2), dtype= object)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        HRI[i,j]=  (omy/2)*Hy[i,j]

#unknown variables
DR = m.Array(m.Var,(2,2), value=0, lb= -10, ub= 10)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        if i==j:
            DR[i,j].value = 1
        else:
            DR[i, j].value= 0

DI = m.Array(m.Var,(2,2),value=0, lb= -10, ub= 10)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        DI[i, j].value=0

#Equations
m.Equations([np.transpose(DR)[i,j]*DR[i,j].dt() \
            +np.transpose(DI)[i,j]*DI[i,j].dt()== \
             np.dot(np.transpose(DR),np.dot(HRR, DI))[i,j] \
            +np.dot(np.transpose(DR),np.dot(HRI, DR))[i,j] \
            -np.dot(np.transpose(DI),np.dot(HRR, DR))[i,j] \
            +np.dot(np.transpose(DI),np.dot(HRI, DI))[i,j] \
             for i in range(2) for j in range(2)])

m.Equations([np.transpose(DR)[i,j]*DI[i,j].dt() \
           - np.transpose(DI)[i,j]*DR[i,j].dt()== \
            (omg/2)*Hx[i,j]- np.dot(np.transpose(DR),np.dot(HRR, DR))[i,j] \
            +np.dot(np.transpose(DR),np.dot(HRI, DI))[i,j] \
            -np.dot(np.transpose(DI),np.dot(HRR, DI))[i,j] \
            -np.dot(np.transpose(DI),np.dot(HRI, DR))[i,j] \
             for i in range(2) for j in range(2)])

#final time
p = np.zeros(int(tg*sample_rate))
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

#Objectives

#m.Obj(omx*final)
#m.Obj(omy*final)
#m.Obj(det*final)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        m.Obj((DR[i,j]- np.identity(2)[i,j])*final)
        m.Obj(DI[i,j]*final)

# solve DAE
m.options.SOLVER= 3
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.MAX_ITER=500
m.solve(disp= True, debug=0)

# solve same problem
# don't update initial conditions with next time step
m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 0
# Soft Constraints
omx.DCOST=0.00001
omy.DCOST=0.00001
det.DCOST=0.00001
# Hard Constraints
#omx.DMAX=0.5
#omy.DMAX=0.5
#det.DMAX=0.5
m.options.MAX_ITER = 200
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)
```

Here is the output of the two solves:

**Solution 1 with IPOPT (initialization)**

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :    28.2295999999915      sec
 Objective      :   -24.7864751130543     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

**Solution 2 with APOPT (includes DCOST)**

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    194.506400000013      sec
 Objective      :   -24.7850777939794     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

There is [additional information](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0098135415001179) on initialization strategies.

> Safdarnejad, S.M., Hedengren, J.D., Lewis, N.R., Haseltine, E., Initialization Strategies for Optimization of Dynamic Systems, Computers and Chemical Engineering, 2015, Vol. 78, pp. 39-50, DOI: 10.1016/j.compchemeng.2015.04.016.